# How to transform a csv string into a Spark-ML compatible Dataset<Row> format?

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-ml, apache-spark-dataset

I have a `Dataset<Row> df`, that contains two columns ("key" and "value") of type `string`. df.printSchema(); is giving me the following output:

```
root
 |-- key: string (nullable = true)
 |-- value: string (nullable = true)
```

The content of the value column is actually a csv formated line (coming from a kafka topic), with the last entry of that line representing the class label and all the previous entries beeing the features (first row not included in the dataset):

```
feature0,feature1,label
0.6720004294237854,-0.4033586564886893,0
0.6659082469383558,0.07688976580256132,0
0.8086502311695247,0.564354801275521,1
```

Since I would like to train a classifier on this data, I need to transform this representation into a row of type dense vector, containing all the feature values and a column of type double, containing the label value:

```
root
 |-- indexedFeatures: vector (nullable = false)
 |-- indexedLabel: double (nullable = false)
```

How can I do this, using java 1.8 and Spark 2.2.0?

Edit: I got further, but while attempting to make it work with a flexible amount feature dimensions, I got stuck again. I created a [follow-up question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49676184/unexpected-encoder-behaviour-when-applying-a-flatmap-operation-on-a-apache-spark)

Comment: Why not load the CSV into a data frame that has `value` as individual columns? From there, spark has an assembler that you can use to create a feature vector. Look at `spark.read.csv`

Comment: It think your hint is going into the right direction. Thing is, I currently get the initial Dataset by using spark.read().format("kafka")...

Comment: So I'm not starting from a blank csv file, but from a kafka topic containing strings.

After that, I have two columns containing raw byte arrays. I tried to use (kafka) deserializers, but I got an error message telling me, that they are not used and I should do the conversion via dataset operations.

I found out, that I can convert the raw byte values into strings by using:
df = df.selectExpr("CAST(key as STRING)", "CAST(value AS STRING)");

spark.read().csv() takes a Dataset<String>. But I have a Dataset<Row> with two string columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A [VectorAssembler](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/ml-features.html#vectorassembler) ([javadocs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/api/java/index.html?org/apache/spark/ml/feature/VectorAssembler.html)) can transform the dataset into the required format.

First, the input is split into three columns:

```java
Dataset<FeaturesAndLabelData> featuresAndLabelData = inputDf.select("value").as(Encoders.STRING())
  .flatMap(s -> {
    String[] splitted = s.split(",");
    if (splitted.length == 3) {
      return Collections.singleton(new FeaturesAndLabelData(
        Double.parseDouble(splitted[0]),
        Double.parseDouble(splitted[1]), 
        Integer.parseInt(splitted[2]))).iterator();
    } else {
      // apply some error handling...
      return Collections.emptyIterator();
    }
  }, Encoders.bean(FeaturesAndLabelData.class));
```

The result is then transformed by a VectorAssembler:

```java
VectorAssembler assembler = new VectorAssembler()
  .setInputCols(new String[] { "feature1", "feature2" })
  .setOutputCol("indexedFeatures");
Dataset<Row> result = assembler.transform(featuresAndLabelData)
  .withColumn("indexedLabel", functions.col("label").cast("double"))
  .select("indexedFeatures", "indexedLabel");
```

The result dataframe has the required format:

```
+----------------------------------------+------------+
|indexedFeatures                         |indexedLabel|
+----------------------------------------+------------+
|[0.6720004294237854,-0.4033586564886893]|0.0         |
|[0.6659082469383558,0.07688976580256132]|0.0         |
|[0.8086502311695247,0.564354801275521]  |1.0         |
+----------------------------------------+------------+

root
 |-- indexedFeatures: vector (nullable = true)
 |-- indexedLabel: double (nullable = true)
```

FeaturesAndLabelData is a simple Java bean to make sure that the column names are correct:

```
public class FeaturesAndLabelData {
  private double feature1;
  private double feature2;
  private int label;

  //getters and setters...
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, this is actually a correct answer to my question. However, it seems very static in the number of features it can process. Say, I have different datasets that I want to convert, with different numbers of features, is there a way to make this solution working with an arbritrary number of feature dimensions?

Comment: I edited my question to how far I got now. I tried to make it more flexible for arbritrary dimensions, but I'm stuck at the very last step.

Comment: I created a follow-up question at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49676184/unexpected-encoder-behaviour-when-applying-a-flatmap-operation-on-a-apache-spark

Answer (score 1):

You have different ways of achieving this.

Create a schema as per your CSV file.

```
public class CSVData implements Serializable {
  String col1;
  String col2;
  long col3;
  String col4;
  //getters and setters  
}
```

Then convert the file into an RDD.

```
JavaSparkContext sc;
JavaRDD<String> data = sc.textFile("path-to-csv-file");
JavaSQLContext sqlContext = new JavaSQLContext(sc);

JavaRDD<Record> csv_rdd = sc.textFile(data).map(
  new Function<String, Record>() {
      public Record call(String line) throws Exception {
         String[] fields = line.split(",");
         Record sd = new Record(fields[0], fields[1], fields[2].trim(), fields[3]);
         return sd;
      }
});
```

Or

Create a Spark Session to read the file as a Dataset.

```
SparkSession spark = SparkSession
                .builder()
                .appName("SparkSample")
                .master("local[*]")
                .getOrCreate();
//Read file
Dataset<Row> ds = spark.read().text("path-to-csv-file");
 or
Dataset<Row> ds = spark.read().csv("path-to-csv-file");
ds.show();
```

Comment: First, thank you very much for your answer and effort, but it's not exactly what I was asking for: 

The first solution end with a JavaRDD<Record>, not with a Dataset<Row>. I need to be able to feed the output directly to one of the Spark ML (not MLLib!) classifiers fit methods. Therefore, I need it to be in Dataset<Row> format, and there in two-column, one dense vector double type, the other double type.

The second solution is reading it from a csv-file. But I don't have a csv-file. I have a Kafka-Topic containing csv-style strings, or, a Dataset<Row> containing a column of Strings.

Comment: Thanks for explaining.