# Unexpected encoder behaviour when applying a flatMap operation on a Apache Spark Dataset<Row>

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-dataset

I'm trying to convert a csv-string that actually contains double values into a spark-ml compatible dataset. Since I don't know the number of features to be expected beforehand, I decided to use a helper class "Instance", that already contains the right datatypes to be used by the classifiers and that is working as intended in some other cases already:

```
public class Instance implements Serializable {
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 6091606543088855593L;
    private Vector indexedFeatures;
    private double indexedLabel;
    ...getters and setters for both fields...
}
```

The part, where I get the unexpected behaviour is this one:

```
    Encoder<Instance> encoder = Encoders.bean(Instance.class);
    System.out.println("encoder.schema()");
    encoder.schema().printTreeString();
    Dataset<Instance> dfInstance = df.select("value").as(Encoders.STRING())
              .flatMap(s -> {
                String[] splitted = s.split(",");

                int length = splitted.length;
                double[] features = new double[length-1];
                for (int i=0; i<length-1; i++) {
                    features[i] = Double.parseDouble(splitted[i]);
                }

                if (length < 2) {
                    return Collections.emptyIterator();
                } else {
                    return Collections.singleton(new Instance( 
                        Vectors.dense(features), 
                        Double.parseDouble(splitted[length-1])
                        )).iterator();
                }
              }, encoder);

    System.out.println("dfInstance");
    dfInstance.printSchema();
    dfInstance.show(5);
```

And I get the following output on the console:

```
encoder.schema()
root
 |-- indexedFeatures: vector (nullable = true)
 |-- indexedLabel: double (nullable = false)

dfInstance
root
 |-- indexedFeatures: struct (nullable = true)
 |-- indexedLabel: double (nullable = true)

+---------------+------------+
|indexedFeatures|indexedLabel|
+---------------+------------+
|             []|         0.0|
|             []|         0.0|
|             []|         1.0|
|             []|         0.0|
|             []|         1.0|
+---------------+------------+
only showing top 5 rows
```

The encoder schema is correctly displaying the indexedFeatures row datatype to be a vector. But when I apply the encoder and do the transformation, it will give me a row of type struct, containing no real objects.

I would like to understand, why Spark is providing me with a struct type instead of the correct vector one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, my answer is not an explanation why you get a struct type. But based on the [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49635401/2129801), I can probably offer a workaround.

The original input is parsed with [DataFrameReader's csv function](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/DataFrameReader.html#csv-org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset-), and the again a [VectorAssembler](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/ml-features.html#vectorassembler) is used:

```java
Dataset<Row> csv = spark.read().option("inferSchema", "true")
  .csv(inputDf.select("value").as(Encoders.STRING()));
String[] fieldNames = csv.schema().fieldNames();    
VectorAssembler assembler = new VectorAssembler().setInputCols(
  Arrays.copyOfRange(fieldNames, 0, fieldNames.length-1))
  .setOutputCol("indexedFeatures");
Dataset<Row> result = assembler.transform(csv)
  .withColumn("indexedLabel", functions.col(fieldNames[fieldNames.length-1]))
  .select("indexedFeatures", "indexedLabel");
```

Comment: Thank you soo much! That is solving my actual problem. Can you give me a tip, where I can learn this kind of spark coding? I tried hard to work with the official documentation, but most of the java part is just sparsely documented. Can you recommend a book, course or whatever where I can study and learn this?

Comment: I agree that the documentation for the java part isn't the best one. Usually, I use the Scala docs and code examples and try then to convert it to Java.

Comment: I tried that as well, but sometimes it's just not that easy. However, thank you very much for all the help.